# Apply function to each list in numpy array of lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that accepts a list (of strings). It does some processing on that list and returns another list of strings, possibly of shorter length.

Now, I have a numpy array of input lists of strings. I want to apply this transformation function to each list in my array.

From what searching I have done so far, it seemed like [vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) or [apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) might be good candidates, but neither is working as expected.

I'd like to do this as efficiently as possible. Ultimately the input array will contain on the order of 100K lists.

I suppose I could iterate over the numpy array in a `for` loop, then `append` each output list into a new output array one at a time, but that seems horribly inefficient.

Here is what I've tried. For testing purposes, I've made a dumbed down transformation function and the input array contains just 3 lists.

```
def my_func(l):
    # accepts list, returns another list
    # dumbed down list transformation function
    # for testing, just return the first 2 elems of original list
    return l[0:2]

test_arr = np.array([['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'], ['lorem', 'ipsum'], ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']])

np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 0, test_arr)
Out[51]: array([['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'], ['lorem', 'ipsum']], dtype=object)

# Rather than applying item by item, this returns the first 2 elements of the entire outer array!!

# Expected:
# array([['the', 'quick'], ['lorem', 'ipsum'], ['this', 'is']])

# Attempt 2...

my_func_vec = np.vectorize(my_func)
my_func_vec(test_arr)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-56-f9bbacee645c>", line 1, in <module>
    my_func_vec(test_arr)

  File "C:\Users\Tony\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2218, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

  File "C:\Users\Tony\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2291, in _vectorize_call
    copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])

ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence
```

Comment: This has been discussed many times.  Neither `vectorize` or `apply...` will improve `efficiency`.  They still have to call your function on each list and accumulate the results in an array or list.  In the big picture it's running your function 100k times that will be slow, not the iteration framework.

Comment: In past testing I found that `np.frompyfunc` is a good tool for iterating on object arrays.

Comment: Actually I thought exactly the same but decided to answer the question instead of telling how I would do it. But then I tested it and for some reason the vectorize was 10x faster than list comprehension or the map() function... any Idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docstring of `vectorize` it reads about the optional argument `otypes`

```
otypes : str or list of dtypes, optional
    The output data type. It must be specified as either a string of
    typecode characters or a list of data type specifiers. There should
    be one data type specifier for each output.
```

It allows you to create structured arrays having complex output, but also solves your problem where you have lists as array element.

`my_func_vec = np.vectorize(my_func, otypes=[list])`

Comment: numpy is oriented to deal efficiently with numerical arrays. I'd check carefully if the vectorization you're doing gives you any performance gain compared to the list comprehention given by @Wli

Answer (score 2):

Some comparisons and time tests; but keep in mind that is a small example.

```
In [106]: test_arr = np.array([['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'], ['lorem', 'ipsum'], ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']])
     ...: 
In [107]: def my_func(l):
     ...:     # accepts list, returns another list
     ...:     # dumbed down list transformation function
     ...:     # for testing, just return the first 2 elems of original list
     ...:     return l[0:2]
     ...:
```

The list comprehension method returns a 2d array of strings - because the function returns 2 element lists each time.

```
In [108]: np.array([my_func(x) for x in test_arr])
Out[108]: 
array([['the', 'quick'],
       ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
       ['this', 'is']],
      dtype='<U5')
```

The input array is object dtype because the sublists differ in length:

```
In [109]: test_arr
Out[109]: 
array([list(['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']), list(['lorem', 'ipsum']),
       list(['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'])], dtype=object)
```

`frompyfunc` returns an object dtype array; consistent with my past tests it is modestly faster (2x but never an order of magnitude)

```
In [110]: np.frompyfunc(my_func,1,1)(test_arr)
Out[110]: 
array([list(['the', 'quick']), list(['lorem', 'ipsum']),
       list(['this', 'is'])], dtype=object)

In [111]: timeit np.frompyfunc(my_func,1,1)(test_arr)
5.68 µs ± 230 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [112]: timeit np.array([my_func(x) for x in test_arr])
8.96 µs ± 25.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`vectorize` uses `frompyfunc` but has more overhead.  The `otypes` is need to avoid the `sequence` error (otherwise it tries to deduce the return type from a trial calculation):

```
In [113]: np.vectorize(my_func,otypes=[object])(test_arr)
Out[113]: 
array([list(['the', 'quick']), list(['lorem', 'ipsum']),
       list(['this', 'is'])], dtype=object)
In [114]: timeit np.vectorize(my_func,otypes=[object])(test_arr)
30.4 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice, although I'd say that for the pure python solution doesn't make sense to do the casting into a numpy array or having the input as numpy arrays.

Comment: As i said, i tested it the same way and had it 10x faster using vectorize compared to list comprehension. But I used a "very long" test_arr... something like 100k

Answer (score 1):

```
[my_func(x) for x in test_arr]
```

You need to go one level down, your solution only outputs the 2 first items of your array rather than the 2 first items of each item of your array.